# Why is Javascript RegExp test giving "false" for a unicode value of this character?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I need to get rid of "↵" characters from the string, but I get some strange behavior from RegExp. Can someone explain this:

```
var str = "↵Since we are starting our webservice...";

alert(str.charAt(0))
alert(str.charCodeAt(0));

alert(/\u8629/.test("↵"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SXYAn/1/

String object methods tell me unicode code for "↵" is 8629, but RegExp says that's not the case.

Comment: why not `alert(/↵/g.test(str));` ?

Comment: That just tells me that the character is present in my string, and I know that already. What I have to do is replace(/\u8629/gm, ''), but that doesn't work because the RegExp is behaving like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get the charCode back as a decimal number and when testing in regEx you need to use a HEX number.

8629=0x21b5.

I used [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20101104085449/http://hamstersoup.com/javascript/regexp_character_class_tester.html) to figure it out.

Comment: You, sir, have just saved a single programmer's life. The right unicode to use with RegExp is \u21b5.